# Check columns against each other in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large data frame of some "signal" columns and "response" columns:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:             
                    response1   response2    signal1    signal2    signal3
       2020-01-01        True       False       True       True      False
       2020-01-02        True        True      False       True      False
       2020-01-03       False        True       True      False      False
```

I want to check each pair of (response, signal) and return a multi-indexed data frame:

```
In [2]: true_positive
Out[2]:               
                    response1                        response2
                      signal1    signal2    signal3    signal1    signal2    signal3
       2020-01-01        True       True      False      False      False       True
       2020-01-02       False       True      False      False       True      False 
       2020-01-03       False       True       True       True      False      False
```

There must be a way with map method that does require a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `concat` after split the df to two

```
r = df.filter(like = 'response')
s = df.filter(like = 'signal')
out = pd.concat([s.eq(r[x], axis=0)for x in r.columns], keys=r.columns, axis=1)
out
Out[229]: 
           response1                 response2                
             signal1 signal2 signal3   signal1 signal2 signal3
2020-01-01      True    True   False     False   False    True
2020-01-02     False    True   False     False    True   False
2020-01-03     False    True    True      True   False   False
```